# Music sign question

Tags: terminology

[image: Music sign]

What does this sign mean?I see it in my score and don't know what I entered.I'd like to delete it.
I am using the newer version of Reflow. MacBook Pro OSX El Capitan Ver 10.11.6

Comment: That looks like the typographic pilcrow symbol (or paragraph marker): ¶.

Comment: I'd guess that this symbol would go away if you were to print the page or save as a pdf.

Comment: @xerotolerant -- I didn't post an answer at first because it isn't really a music question; but I guess if this is causing problems in a music notation program that is close enough.... Answer posted below.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol ¶ is known as a "pilcrow". In typography, it is a paragraph marker. [The Wikipedia page on the pilcrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow) contains some information about its history and uses.

I don't know of any standard use in music for the pilcrow, and don't know why it is appearing in Reflow for you. I remember hearing about this symbol showing up in MS Word occasionally, when users inadvertently clicked the wrong menu selection; I think in that case there was a checkbox for paragraph marking. I don't know if Reflow has something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out but I don't know what the button is supposed to do. The Reflow Manual is not up to date.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a musical symbol, but presumably some kind of formatting symbol within Reflow.

I searched the Reflow manual online, but didn't find a way to toggle off such formatting symbols. Try looking for something within a drop-down menu that may toggle this off.